# How to download a 61th minute video for 5 seconds remotely?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

As you can quickly download video from a remote part of a large video file with ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:00:00 -i http://example.com/videofile.flv -t 00:01:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.flv
```

Here I miss the first hour of video and download 61th minutes. It takes 20 minutes. Time of the operation = end of video and splitting it locally.

**How can I speed up the process?**

Comment: full uncut console output please? is it taking 20M before it starts "doing" anything? (my guess is its downloading the whole first hour for some reason...)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the server, and container. If the HTTP server supports range-requests, you can start downloading at any byte you wish. Next you need to know what byte to start from. in an MP4 file, the 'moov' box has that information. In the case of flv, there is no such "frame index" To determine where a frame starts in an flv, you need to know the position and size of the the previous frame, all the way back to the start of the file. Theoretically, you could attempt attempt a sort of binary search using range requests, and attempt to find FLV tags within a random buffer. But ffmpeg will not do that for you.